# Function Growth Question

Tags: exponential-function

Which is greater as $n$ gets larger, $f(n) = 2^{2^{2^n}}$ or $g(n) = 100^{100^n}$?

I tried differentiating the terms but it didn't really reveal anything. Can anyone come up with a solution?

Thanks in advance for any contributions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try comparing $$\ln \ln f(n) \quad \text{vs} \quad \ln \ln g(n).$$ That works in all similar cases.

Comment: I haven't come across the convention for taking the log of numbers raised to the power multiple times. Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: I think I get (2^n+1)(ln(2)) and (n+1)(ln(100))? I assume the answer is f(n), but is that proof enough? Sorry for the poor formatting, I'm on my phone.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: $\log a^b=b\log a$. It doesn't matter if $b$ happens to be an expression involving powers. Just remember that $r^{s^t}$ means $r^{(s^t)}$ and not $(r^s)^t$. So you have that $\log r^{s^t}= s^t\log r$.

Comment: Ok thanks. So is f(n) the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still left, is this sufficient proof?

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{2^{2^n}}}{100^{100^n}}
\\=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \ln \ln 2^{2^{2^n}}}{\ln \ln 100^{100^n}}
\\=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n \ln 2 + \ln \ln 2}{n \ln 100 + \ln \ln 100}
\\=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n}
\\= +\infty$

Comment: Not quite. It is not true in general that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln \ln f(n)}{\ln \ln g(n)}$$ because logarithm softens the difference between orders of magnitude. But what you've written suffices to show that $\ln \ln f(n) > \ln \ln g(n)$ for large $n$, so $f(n) > g(n)$.